# multipart form data for post in python

Tags: python, api, post, directory, multipartform-data

Can someone explain to me what multi part form data is. I am trying to post something into an api using python but it seems that i need to use multi part form data and not just the json file. Am i able to post multiple json files with this form of data?

with a quick google search I was able to upload 1 file in this formate but i would like to understand the formate of it and how to use it/ if it can be used to upload multiple files.

My project goal is to automate this process where I place Json files into a folder on my computer and run a script where 1 by 1 it uploads it into API but not sure how to do it with the multipart form data

```
files = {
    'file': open("filltest.json",'rb')
}


response = requests.post(url=api_endpoint, files=files)
```

this is what i was able to create after googling it but an explanation would be super helpful.

thanks!

Comment: check out req toolbelt, specificlay the multipartencoder

Comment: when POST has to send many files (or files and data)  then it has to show where are beginning of files and what ate types of files (and what filenames they have) - so in header it adds information  how it will recognize beginning of file - ie. using line `---file`, and next it will add this line and lines with file size (and file type, file name), next empty line, and next file data. After first file it will add again `---file` for next file. etc.

Comment: maybe use flask/django to create own local www server, and send POST with file to your server, and in server display all data which you get to see how it looks like. Eventually you could run local proxy server like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and use it when you send POST - and in Charles you will see full request with all details - and you will see how it is constructed..

Comment: as I know when you use module `requests` then it automatically create all what you need - you can use `post(..., files=..., data=...)` to send files and data at the same time and it will have to built multipart request.